# Having problems with divs overlapping, would like to set fixed position

Tags: html, css

I'm new to stackoverflow and so I apologize in advance for rehashing any issues already addressed here (I'm sure they are, just not sure how the apply to my specific situation).

Anyway here is the site I'm working on - [www.betsyandalex2013.com](http://www.betsyandalex2013.com). I would like to have all of the elements fixed in place. I've been playing around with it using Firebug but when I use `position: fixed;` on say `#wrap` I can't scroll over to see the rest of the content. Alternately, when I fix the position of `#header`, the links disappear. Again, I would ideally like to fix all the elements in place and be able to scroll across (and up/down) to see any content when the browser is resized.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you said. But setting:
    #header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
It will work: The header will be out of the natural flux of your page and it will be at top of the screen even when you scroll down/up.

PS: To see the effect put content to #wrap element.

Comment: I see what you're saying but I'm actually fine with it being fixed at the top. The issue is more when I resize the browser and scroll left/right, the header menu and body content overlap the background image. If however I set the #body position as fixed, I can no longer scroll left/right to see the rest of the site content.

Comment: So you don't want a top/down scroll. What do you want is a left/right scroll, right? If I've understood you it means that #wrap el will have a lot of width. In that case the header is fixed at top and I can see the the "content" scrolling left/right without problems.

Comment: What I've test in the link you said is: #wrap {width: 3000px;} to simulate content.